# FACEBOOK API - POWER BI - ERROR TO IMPORT AD_NAME AND ADSET_NAME

Tags: facebook-graph-api, powerbi

I'm trying to import data of leads from FACEBOOK API to POWER BI. But, the **"ad_name"** and **"adset_name"** it's not appearing. I'm usign the bellow code:

act_548351656683396/insights?time_range={"since":"2022-01-01","until":"2022-09-30"}&level=ad&level=adset&level=campaign&fields=adset_name,campaign_name,ad_name,spend,objective,created_time,clicks,frequency,impressions,reach,actions&limit=5000 +access

I'd like to see too, the data per day. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

to help you with this it would require more details, are you using some tool to pull this data? does this tool support these field? might it be an issue with the limit ?